# Filtering data from API with Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, api, sequelize.js

The data I pulled from the API I use is as follows:

```
{
    "result": [
        [
            {
                "EmailID": "example@example.com",
                "Address": "blablabla",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Marital_status": "Single",
                "Upload_Residence_Permit": "",
                "ApprovalStatus": "Approval Not Enabled",
                "Department": "SOFTWARE",
            }
         ]
     ]
}
```

The function I wrote is as follows:

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    try{
        const result = await meService.getMe(req.body.email);
        return res.status(200).send({result});
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).json({status: false, message: `${e}`});
    }
})
```

My input parameter is email. I am pulling my data from api by typing email in postman.

The problem is that I want to filter out certain data from these data. Like Gender, Department.

The function I wrote for this is as follows:

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        const result = await meService.getMe(req.body.email)
            //.filter(zohoService => zohoService)
         const res = result.map(({ FirstName, LastName, Department }) => ({
            FirstName,
            LastName,
            Department,
        }));
         return res
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).json({status: false, message: `${e}`});
    }
})
```

But the function I wrote does not work. What fixes should I make for this? What path should I follow?

Comment: It's basically a typo. You assigned your array from `.map` to the `res` parameter you received (the Response object from Express) and then never sent a response (your updated code doesn't do `res.status(200).send({result})` (and can't if you reassign `res`). You should change `const result` to `let result` and then reassign `result`, and use the same code you used originally after the `filter` to return it. (You don't *have* to do it in two steps, you could do `const result = (await meService.getMe(req.body.email)).map(/*...*/);` and then, again, follow it with the code sending the response.)

Comment: thank you. I did as you said but it froze result blank

Comment: If your initial code works but includes things you don't want, then [this](https://pastebin.com/Rcw5gEMx) definitely works. If the initial code doesn't work, well, you have to fix that part of things separately. :-) (I'd probably use `.json` instead of `.send` in the `if` block, though.)

Comment: thank you. I had to change the code blog. let name = result[0][0].FirstName; I got the result by indexing with .